Labels not displaying in CustomTkinter GUI
I am writing a Python script using CustomTkinter to display system stats on a little monitor that will be connected to a Raspberry Pi. The code outputs the CPU and RAM usage to the console and updates every 2 seconds as it should, yet I am not seeing any text on my GUI when I launch it...
Here's the code:
import customtkinter as ctk
import psutil

ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
ctk.set_default_color_theme("green")

app = ctk.CTk()
app.geometry("320x240")

# function to get CPU usage
def get_cpu_usage():
    return psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)

# function to get RAM usage
def get_ram_usage():
    return psutil.virtual_memory().percent

# Create labels for displaying system stats
cpu_label = ctk.CTkLabel(app, text="CPU Usage: ", fg_color="red")
cpu_label.pack(pady=10)
ram_label = ctk.CTkLabel(app, text="RAM Usage: ")
ram_label.pack(pady=10)

# Main Function
def display_system_stats():
    cpu = get_cpu_usage()
    ram = get_ram_usage()
    
    #Debug to print to console
    print(f'Updating stats: CPU Usage: {cpu}%, RAM Usage: {ram}%')
    
    cpu_label.configure(text=f'CPU Usage: {cpu}%')
    ram_label.configure(text=f'RAM Usage: {ram}%')
    
    app.after(2000, display_system_stats)

# Start the periodic update
app.after(0, display_system_stats)

app.mainloop()

Any help would be appreciated!
I have tried debugging, and printing to console to ensure the function is working

What is the problem? The program works good for me

Issue resolved... I was using python 3.9... upon changing my intepreter to 3.12.1 it works perfectly
